# RxSwift - Replayed Tap Events

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, rx-swift

When the user taps on a button I display a selection screen. The result is passed into my view model. The code looks like this:

```
locationButton.rx.tap
            .flatMapLatest(wireframe.displayPlaceSelection)
            .filterNil()
            .map(DiscoverLocationSelection.location)
            .subscribe(onNext: viewModel.updateLocation(with:))
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This code works fine, and the user may select a location and will be returned to this screen with the button.

If the user then taps the button a second time, the `displayPlaceSelection()` function is called twice. If the user were to do this a third time, the function will be called 3 times. This results in multiple view controllers being pushed on top of each other.

How can I stop these events from stacking up?

The effect is this:

[image: RxSwift Tap Replay]

Comment: I can suppose that this code (subscribe) is called every time when you open this vc and thus you have many subscribers to the tap event. Where is this code? `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` for example.

Comment: You're entirely correct! Thank you so much.
Please post this comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suppose that this code (subscribe) is called every time when you open this vc and thus you have many subscribers to the tap event. Where is this code? `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` for example.